# Repeating other column values when using pandas.Series.explode()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe of the form

```
    a           b
0   [a, b]      0
1   [c, d, e]   1
```

I have written a function to create a list of partial lists:

```
def partials(l):
    result = []
    for i, elem in enumerate(l):
        result.append(l[:i+1])
    return result
```

which, when applied to the series `df['a']`, and exploding, using `d['a'].apply(partials).explode()`  correctly gives:

```
0          [a]
0       [a, b]
1          [c]
1       [c, d]
1    [c, d, e]
```

However, this series is necessarily longer than the original. How can I apply this function in-place to column `a` of my dataframe, such that the column `b` repeats its value wherever the corresponding line from the original dataframe is 'exploded', like this :

```
            a     b
0          [a]    0
0       [a, b]    0
1          [c]    1
1       [c, d]    1
1    [c, d, e]    1
```

?

Comment: You could do with your original code and slight modification on `explode`. 
Assign first: `df['a'] = df['a'].apply(partials)`, then explode on column "a": `df.explode('a')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join back:

```
(df['a'].apply(partials)
   .explode().to_frame()
   .join(df.drop('a', axis=1))
)
```

Output:

```
           a  b
0        [a]  0
0     [a, b]  0
1        [c]  1
1     [c, d]  1
1  [c, d, e]  1
```